# CSS :not selector doesn't work

Tags: css, selector

This is probably a really stupid question, but I can't get the :not selector to work in css. I want to color all text in my page unless it has a class called "nocolor". Here's the code, I don't see the problem:

```css
*:not(.nocolor) {
    color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hello</h2>
<h2 class="nocolor">Hello</h2>
```

Comment: I would really like to know why this is the case.  Every browser I tested it on had the same behaviour.  I imagine it has to be in the spec somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was surprised by this behavior but the * selector applies to *everything* so you have to look out for application to parent elements as well (like body and html tags themselves).

You can fix it by adding `body` to the selector, like so:

```
body *:not(.nocolor) {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: adding `* { color: #000; /* or whatever */ }` before the `*:not()` selector also works.

Comment: Is it possible to apply the not selector to all children inside it? If I want to change the color of a p tag that is in a div with the nocolor class, it doesn't work

Comment: Use @JosephMarikle 's comment

Answer (score 2):

Your selector should be written like so:

```
:not(.nocolor) {
    color: #f00;
}
```

Remove the '*', and this will select *everything* on the page.

See docs here: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot)

Answer (score 2):

It's because `*` is applied to every element including `body`, which doesn't have the `.nocolor` class.